# result of std.algorithm.map

Tags: types, dictionary, d

Could somebody say what `std.algorithm.map` returns? (link to some documentation page would be very appreciated)
From error message its result is of type `Result`

```
ulong[] x = [1,2,3];
ulong[] y = std.algorithm.map!"a"(x); // Error: cannot implicitly convert <..> of type Result to ulong[]
```

In http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html#map there is quite little info on it:

```
The call map!(fun)(range) returns a range of which elements are obtained by applying fun(x) left to right for all x in range
```

From this it is not clear, what I can or can not do with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not supposed to know or care what `std.algorithm.map` returns beyond the fact that it's a range of the same genre as the one passed in (forward, bidirectional, random, etc.). It's that way with most range-based functions. They almost always return either a new range which wraps the one passed in or a the exact same type of range as was passed in (e.g. `map` does the former; `find` does the latter). Use `auto`:

```
ulong[] x = [1, 2, 3];
auto y = map!"a"(x);
```

The range returned by `map` is lazy. It doesn't do anything until you iterate over it (it then calls the given function on each successive `front` of the underlying range). It's more efficient that way (as well as enabling infinite ranges). The exact return type depends on the type of range that you passed in and is local to `map` so that you can't create one directly. You need to either use `auto` to infer the type or `typeof` to get the type:

```
typeof(map!"a"(x)) y = map!"a"(x);
```

However, you generally only use `typeof` when you need a variable which you cannot initialize directly. `auto` is almost always the way to go.

If you need to create an array from the result of `map` (or from any other range), then use [`std.array.array`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_array.html#array):

```
ulong[] y = array(map!"a"(x));
```

If you don't know much about ranges, then you should probably read [this](http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/ranges.html). Unfortunately, there isn't currently an article on dlang.org explaining ranges, but that link is for a chapter in a book which one of the members of the D community wrote in Turkish and has been translating to English, and it covers ranges fairly well.

**EDIT**:

Walter Bright recently wrote an article specifically about types which are local to a function but returned by the function which may also help enlighten you. They even get a cool name: [`Voldemort Types in D`](http://www.drdobbs.com/blogs/cpp/232901591).

Comment: "You're not supposed to know or care". Please correct me if I'm wrong, but if I should not know/care, then my example should compile

Comment: I mean that you shouldn't know or care in that all you need to know about it is that it's a range of the same genre as the one passed in. The exact type is specific to `map` and not something that you're going to use. You just use `auto` to infer the type and use the range with the API that ranges have. If you want it to actually be a specific type, then you must convert it to that type with a function which takes a range and will generate the type that you want (e.g. std.array.array).

Comment: It seems unnatural that I am *forced* to use `auto` to use result of map (even if I like laizy eval. and stuff)
Anyway, thanks for the answer & the link

Comment: Well, it's a templated type. And even if `map`'s return type were external to `map`, and you could see exactly what it was, it would be far too ugly to use. At its most basic level, it would be `Map!(int[])`, and once you start passing the result of one range function to another, the types get really ugly really fast. For instance, take `until` - one of the few functions in std.algorithm whose type is external. The type of `until!"a == 7"(intArr)` would be `Until!("a == 7",int[],void)`. Do you really want to type that? std.algorithm is very powerful, but without `auto`, it borders on unusable.

Comment: Also, it's generally considered good practice in D to always use `auto` unless you can't (e.g. for a variable declaration which isn't directly initialized). So, using it for the result of `map` would be the normal thing to do even if it returned an array.

Comment: I would like you to elaborate on "it's generally considered good practice in D to always use auto". It is not obvious what it is on the right hand side of '='. (like in this case) And depending on the type I know what I can or can not do (I'd really appreciate answer)

Comment: I mean that in general, if you can use `auto`, then use `auto`. Don't use the type explicitly unless you have to. Two reasons for this are that it makes refactoring code much easier, since you don't have to change the types of variables when the types being used change, and it helps make your code more generic. This is particularly important when dealing with templates. In general, using `auto` makes your code more maintainable. There are times when you might need to explicitly use a type for more clarity, but I think that you'll find that it's nowhere near as often as you might think.

Comment: And as I pointed out in my answer, this is a case where you don't need to care what the type is. You just need to know that it's a range of ulongs. The exact type is immaterial. You know what you can do with it, because it's a range (as the documentation states), and ranges have a well-defined API (as the book that I linked to explains).

Answer (score 3):

The Result range is 'lazy', it doesn't represent the final result.

It can be turned into an array if you import std.array and wrap it like so:

```
ulong[] y = array(std.algorithm.map!"a"(x));
```

or

```
ulong[] y = std.algorithm.map!"a"(x).array;
```

if you are using dmd 2.059 or later

The map result can also be iterated over directly with foreach:

```
auto result = std.algorithm.map!"a"(x);
foreach (element; result)
  writeln(to!string(element));
```

Comment: @Jonathan He's refering to the UFCS notation

Comment: Ah, okay. I misunderstood and thought that the "dmd 2.059 or later" was referring to the part after that. `array` really should still have parens on it though or it won't compile with `-property` (and `-property` is supposed to become the normal behavior eventually, making the parens required here, since `array` isn't a property).

Answer (score 1):

`Result` is a type inside `map()` that cannot be named because it is a [Voldemort Type](http://www.drdobbs.com/article/print?articleId=232901591&siteSectionName=cpp).

The actual [source code](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/master/std/algorithm.d#L366) in Phobos looks something like this:

```
template map(fun...) if (fun.length >= 1)
{
    auto map(Range)(Range r) if (isInputRange!(Unqual!Range))
    {
        //...
        struct Result
        {
            //...
        }
        return Result(r);
    }
}
```

If you study the source code you will notice that `Result` is nothing but a range:  it has the usual `popFront()` and `empty()` methods, and other methods depending on the kind of range that needs to be returned.  If you use type inference,

```
auto r = map!("a*a")(data);
```

`r` will be typed as `Result`, but you can't directly instantiate it.